# How to downgrade from Mojave to High-Sierra from a partition and without a USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, macos-mojave

I have an older Mac and Mojave graphics aren't functioning properly. It's not my hardware, it's the Metal graphics library, Google Chrome / Safari / any 3rd party app renders graphics normally.

I want to install HighSierra and install it on a partition, I want to do this without using a USB. How can I install and boot from a partition running High Sierra?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think you can do this without the macOS installer for High Sierra running on a USB flash drive.

Comment: Yeah I have the installer

Answer (score 1):

Going back a version of macOS (even point releases) while not difficult is a bit time consuming as there is no built-in un-install or roll-back mechanism built into macOS like there is with Windows (unfortunately...)

The steps are basically

1. Create a bootable USB installer. Though there are terminal commands to do this I use [DiskMakerX](https://diskmakerx.com) which will create the bootable installer for you. Note that there is a version of DiskMakerX for each version of macOS.
2. Back-up your Mac. I prefer making an image of my drive with CCC,SuperDuper or other utility. Though a Time Machine backup works well too.
3. Once you have the (verified bootable) installer, and a good backup boot from the installer and once you get to the Install MacOS screen select disk utility from the Utilities menu and reformat your macOS drive. (hence the necessary backup!)
4. Quit Disk Utility and go back into the installer and set it off to do its thing.
5. At first boot when it asks you to create a user account, make a generic, disposable account (Admin, Temp, etc.) so that you can recreate your original user account which you can't do if you use the same name as your account previously used.
6. Do all the updates you can, get it to the last version of macOS you want.
7. Now you can use TimeMachine to restore your files/apps or (my preference) run  Migration Assistant.app, plug your backup drive into your Mac and point it at the backup drive, choose what you want transferred and let it do its thing.
8. There is no step 8, you are done!